# How to mock React Context in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

I'm trying to test a React component that uses React Context.

Here is the provider component:

```
const ArtifactsResumeContext = createContext<Artifact>({} as Artifact);

export const useArtifactsResumeContext = () => useContext(ArtifactsResumeContext);

const ArtifactsResume = () => {
  useCallOnloadAnimation()
  const { name } = useParams();

  const artifact = ArtifactArray.flat().filter(
    (artifact) => artifact.name === name
  )[0];

  return (
    <ColumnedFlex
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
        gap: 10,
      }}
    >
      <PrevPageArrow />
      <ArtifactsResumeContext.Provider value={artifact}>
        <ArtifactsResumeTitle />
        <ArtifactsResumeContent />
      </ArtifactsResumeContext.Provider>
    </ColumnedFlex>
 );
};

export default ArtifactsResume;
```

Here is one of the consumer components:

```
const ArtifactsResumeTitle = () => {
  const { name } = useArtifactsResumeContext();
  return (
    <IsLoading>
      <Typography
        color='primary'
        variant='h1'
        fontSize={50}
        mt={10}
      >
        {name}
      </Typography>
    </IsLoading>
  );
};

export default ArtifactsResumeTitle;
```

The problem begins when I try to test the component like this:

```
test('Block Link works properly', () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={AppStore()}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ArtifactsResumeContext.Provider value={BodyArtifacts[0]} >
          <ArtifactsBlock src='' name='Christian' />
          <AppRouter />
        </ ArtifactsResumeContext.Provider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  fireEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole('link', {
    hidden: true
  })[0])

  screen.debug()
});
```

Basically ArtifactsBlock component contains the link that redirects to the provider component shown above, and AppRouter is where all my routes are. Then, using fireEvent, I click this link and, for the time being, log what's inside. However I get this errors instead:

*TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(0 , _ArtifactsResume.useArtifactsResumeContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

```
  4 |
  5 | const ArtifactsResumeTitle = () => {
> 6 |       const { name } = useArtifactsResumeContext();
    |               ^
  7 |       return (
  8 |               <IsLoading>
  9 |                       <Typography*
```

I tried mocking context and wrapping my ArtifactsBlock in the Provider but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: try to remove `{}` from `name` in `const name = useArtifactsResumeContext();` and here too `const name = useParams();`

Comment: What is `BodyArtifacts`, or more specifically, `BodyArtifacts[0]`? Where is `useArtifactsResumeContext` used that has the issue? In the `ArtifactsBlock` component code? Please [edit] to include a more complete and cohesive [mcve] so it's clear what the code is doing *and where* it is doing it.

Comment: @nuser137, I can't remove those brackets because I am destructuring and object. It just throws an error at me

Comment: @DrewReese, `BodyArtifacts` is just an array of objects that i randomly picked for the test. It's being imported from another folder and It's of no importance. The context hook causes problems in `ArtifactsResume` children components. In this case it's `ArtifactsResumeTitle`. Resume itself creates context and passes `{name}` down to children but jest doesn't see name as shown above. `ArtifactsBlock` is simply a component that has a link that redirects to the `ResumeComponent` as written above. I don't know how any more complete I can make it. I'll try to reproduce issue with an easier sample

Comment: A complete code example would/should include ***all*** the components/code between the Context provider component and the component consuming the context.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap your application with the Context Provider

```
    <YourContextName.Provider value={YourValue}>
       //The Rest Of Your App
    </YourContext.Provider>
```

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Just edited the test in the question

Comment: in your consumer try to useContext instead of importing it directly from your consumer

`const {name} = useContext(ArtifactsResumeContext)`

Comment: I just tried and nothing. Still the same error